# How create a favorites table that connects to a customer mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement a favorites table in mysql that allows the user to add a restaurant object to the table by id number. Here is the basic outline:
There are customers which contain an unique id and other stuff. Then there are restaurants that contain a unique id and other stuff. I want the customers to be able to have favorites. I made a favorites table that has the id of the customer - this is the way I would look up a customers favorites - but then I would have to hard code a set number of columns that I can store the unique restaurant id's in.

Would it make sense to dynamically add columns to the favorites database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is a many-to-many relationship, and the usual way to implement this is through a join table like this:

```
users
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Jill |
+----+------+

restaurants
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | McDonald's |
|  2 | Subway     |
|  3 | Chipotle   |
+----+------------+

favorites
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | restaurant_id |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |             2 |
|       1 |             3 |
|       2 |             3 |
+---------+---------------+
```

Each row in the `favorites` table is a "user favorited restaurant" relationship. In this scenario, nobody has favorited McDonald's, John has favorited Subway, and both John and Jill have favorited Chipotle.

SQLAlchemy has excellent support for this pattern:

```
class Favorite(Base):
    __tablename__ = "favorites"
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
    restaurant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("restaurants.id"), primary_key=True)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    favorites = relationship("Restaurant", secondary=Favorite.__table__)

class Restaurant(Base):
    __tablename__ = "restaurants"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: when I set up the Favorites(Model) It gives me an error because it says I do not have a primary key. How can I solve this?

Comment: @LouisB Sorry about that. I've edited the example. The idea is to create a composite primary key on `(user_id, restaurant_id)`.

Comment: I want users to be able to have as many favorites as I want so if I make the primary key the users id, that means no user can have more than one favorites correct?

Comment: @LouisB That's correct -- that's why you shouldn't make the primary key `(user_id)`; instead, it should be `(user_id, restaurant_id)`.

Comment: oh, so should i just have an autoincrement integer be the primary key?

Comment: Also, How would I query the restaurants to filter the restaurants only by the users favorites?

Comment: @LouisB No, you don't need an autoincrement primary key column on `favorites`. At the risk of repeating myself again, you need to have a **composite primary key** on `(user_id, restaurant_id)`. This is specified by having `primary_key=True` on both columns. Copy the example, it will work. For your second question, you should go through the [ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship). It answers these basic question. But, very briefly, you would query a user first, `u = session.query(User).first()`, then access `u.favorites` on it.